# How to detect if Python CLI tool was called from an invalid directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I have been working on a CLI tool in Python 3.9 to generate a template project and ran into a strange edge case when the tool is called from a Windows directory that has been deleted.

Instead of raising some sort of error because I called the tool from a path like: `C:\Users\...\Projects\a-deleted-folder`, Python sets the working directory to `C:\` happily generates files anyways.

For example, my CLI tool is called `qtdk` and if I call it in a deleted folder like so:

```
PS C:\Users\...\Projects\a-deleted-folder> qtdk init
```

It instead acts like it was called like this:

```
PS C:\> qtdk init
```

What I would like to happen, is for this to raise an error since I don't want to start generating files in the `C:\` directory if I try to initialize a project in a directory that does not exist.

Is there any way to detect if this is happening and raise an exception?

I've tried checking `sys.argv` and `os.getcwd()` but neither seem to provide any indication of where the tool was originally called.

Comment: What kind of additional details would you like to know?

The problem is that Python sets the working directory to the `C:/` directory if I call the tool in a directory that has been deleted.

What I want to do is to detect when the tool is called in a deleted directory so I can stop it before it generates files, but I'm not sure of a good way to detect when this happens.